# SQL database with temporal data

Tags: database-recommendation

Is it possible to do this in a SQL database

```
 SELECT * FROM Employee
    WHERE BirthDate BETWEEN DATE 1970-01-01 AND DATE 1970-01-01
```

The result that was said to from this query is all the employees that are born on 
1970-01-01.
This query has been taken from the following [book](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf)
Sorry if this question is lacking.

Comment: That's a lot of reading. have you considered something more general for SQL first?

Comment: The correct notation for an ANSI date literal is `DATE '1970-01-01'`. Note the single quotes around the actual date.

Comment: yeah I know it's a lot of reading but I am just skipping through most of it because most of it isn't really interesting on the research I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variety of this, depending on RDBMS. SQL Server and MySQL accept date literals like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
    WHERE BirthDate BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1970-01-01'

SELECT * FROM Employee
    WHERE BirthDate BETWEEN '19700101' AND '19700101'
```

Comment: Oracle would accept either of these as well assuming the proper `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Actaully this would only get the people born at midnight unless you are using SQL Server's date data type and not datetime. If you have times associated, you would want date>='1970-01-01' AND date<'1970-01-02'